# What is the best approach to edit object elements in different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing an android application in which is needed one object which contains an arraylist of objects to be edited.

The idea is each of the objects in the arraylist is to be edited in a different fragment.

The app is using `ORM` to sore objects in database, so I need each object from this arraylist to be edited in different fragments and when save button is pressed to collect the objects from the fragments, to update the main object and save it.

Now I'm creating the fragments and using setters I'm setting the objects for each fragment in the main activity:

```
    DailyFragment fragment2 = new DailyFragment();
    fragment2.setdaySchedule(daySchedule);
    fragment2.setmDayIndex(1);
```

Using this approach in each fragment I have reference to the needed element of the arraylist, so it is not needed anything to be done when the main object is saved.

I need advise if there are better ways this to be achieved?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Fragments should be modular and independent, not much good can come from having to give Fragments the data it should display. It's much better to tell The Fragment what it should display and then let the Fragment fetch, update and manage the data itself. When you update data in one place all other Fragments should update their data automatically and autonomously for example through a change listeners on your database.

Comment: ok How to tell The Fragment what it should display? By setting of some ID from the database in the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider moving your data out of the fragments.

Look into using something like dependency injection ([dagger](https://google.github.io/dagger/)) to create places to keep and modify your data.

Ideally your fragments contain little more than what is needed to display information correctly.  If you bundle everything into activities/fragments you'll continuously be hampered by the need to communicate between them.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I'm looking for some more simple option